# AngularJS - Role Based Navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a application using Ruby on Rails (Devise/CanCan for Authentication/Roles) and a AngularJS client.

I have 3 roles - each with different navigation menus. I'd rather not have 3 different views with different navigation bars- is there a way I can show/hide navigation elements based on which user is loaded?

Anyone familiar with this or have any good ideas? I did some hunting but came up with little to no success... Anything helps!

Comment: [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know you already marked an answer but I wanted to point out a nuance related to performance.

Depending on the size of your menu and HTML you might want to go beyond ng-show to use ng-if. The problem with ng-show is that all of the nodes are compiled, even the ones the user will never use. For example, a Manager may never use the Admin or User nodes but they are still parsed and compiled.

If you use ng-if you can avoid that and only render/compile the fragments when the condition is true. Since you are always going to use the same controller, you wouldn't have to repeat it:

```
<div ng-controller="AccountController"> 
<div ng-if="IsAdmin()">...admin nav...</div>
<div ng-if="IsUser()">...user nav...</div>
</div>
```

We are on a massive Angular application and small changes like this reap major performance benefits. When the "if" expression fails, the element is removed from the DOM and never compiled, vs. ng-show while will still compile the element and simply hide it.

Comment: Awesome - in this case I wish I could have two correct answers!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ng-show tag.

You will do something like this:

```
<div ng-show="IsAdmin()" ng-controller="AccountController" >...admin nav...</div>
<div ng-show="IsUser()" ng-controller="AccountController" >...user nav...</div>
<div ng-show="IsManager()" ng-controller="AccountController" >...manager nav...</div>
```

..Controller

```
$scope.IsAdmin = function(){
    return $scope.UserRole == "Admin";
}

$scope.IsUser = function(){
    return $scope.UserRole == "StandardUser";
}

$scope.IsManager = function(){
    return $scope.UserRole == "Manager";
}
```

In your controller you determine some logic to show each nav based off of the role then return true/false.